# Looking for details on mob hitboxes

Tags: torchlight-2, torchlight

I recently acquired Torchlight as a part of the Humble Bundle, and I've been loving it. (much better than the Diablo-3 disappointment, grumble grumble...)

I have, however, been running into issues with mis-clicks on monsters.  Sometimes I hit the monster when I meant to move, and sometimes I move when I meant to hit the monster.

Looking carefully, it almost looks like the monster hitbox is defined by the square of floor that it's occupying rather than the monster's model itself.  Is this correct?

Can anybody tell me how the hitboxes are defined for mobs in Torchlight?  Bonus points if I could get a similar description for Torchlight 2.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't answer your question per se, but I think you may find it helpful:

If you hold down the Shift key, clicks will always attack rather than moving; attacks will be aimed in the direction of the cursor. I don't know whether they lock onto mobs if you specifically click on one, but I've never had any trouble playing this way, using Shift to “plant my feet” whenever I'm not moving.

If I recall correctly (I haven't been playing recently), there's also a few breakable objects which cannot be targeted, so can only be broken this way.

Comment: From my experiences with diablo, I'd expect this to fire my bow in the exact direction of my cursor rather than at the mob I think I'm pointed at.  Is that how it works?

Comment: @tugs That is indeed how it works.

Comment: You can also hold Ctrl key while clicking the left mouse button, this will cause you to only atack if there is a mob under your mouse cursor (otherwise your character remains in place). This prevents you from runing to the middle of a group of mobs, when miss clicking.